# Encoding Error of Reading .dta Files with Chinese Characters

Tags: pandas, encoding, dta

I am trying to read .dta files with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_stata('filename', encoding='utf-8')
```

the error message is:

```
ValueError: Unknown encoding. Only latin-1 and ascii supported.
```

other encoding formality also didn't work, such as **gb18030** or **gb2312** for dealing with Chineses characters. If I remove the encoding parameter, the DataFrame will be all of garbage values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply read the original data by default encoding, then transfer to the expected encoding! Suppose the column having garbled text is `column1`

```
import pandas as pd
dta = pd.read_stata('filename.dta')
print(dta['column1'][0].encode('latin-1').decode('gb18030'))
```

The `print` result will show normal Chinese characters, and `gb2312` can also make it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of pandas (version 0.22.0), the supported encodings for read_stata are ('ascii', 'us-ascii', 'latin-1', 'latin_1', 'iso-8859-1',                   'iso8859-1', '8859', 'cp819', 'latin', 'latin1', 'L1'). So you can only choose from this list.

Comment: Thanks! But what function should I use then?

Comment: sorry I don't know, because I don't have stata.

Comment: @Xiaodong `read_stata` in pandas 0.23.4 will fail with `ValueError: Unknown encoding. Only latin-1 and ascii supported.`